# What are the various techniques for Approximate Dynamic Programming?

Tags: reinforcement-learning

To overcome the Curse of Dimensionality associated with exact DP what are the various techniques that have been developed ? Is there a good resource which provides a nice overall view of the methods ?

Comment: this is a really broad question. you can take a look at this book http://incompleteideas.net/book/bookdraft2018feb28.pdf

Comment: Another book you can look at is "Approximate Dynamic Programming: Solving the Curses of Dimensionality" by Warren B. Powell https://www.amazon.com/Approximate-Dynamic-Programming-Solving-the-Curses-of-Dimensionality-Wiley-Series-in-Probability-and-Statistics/dp/0470171553/ / You're going to have to put in some intellectual shoe leather.

Comment: I agree it's a broad area, but the question doesn't ask for a full solution, only a list of techniques and some references.  That seems like a reasonable question which could have an answer of reasonable length.